# Array of arrays: Can you directly ReDim an inner array?

Tags: vba

Suppose I want a 10-element array with the first element being a 2-element array. Here's what I would like to do but it causes a compile error:

```
Dim a As Variant: ReDim a(9)
ReDim a(0)(2)
```

This works but it makes a copy and I would like to do it directly, if possible:

```
Dim a As Variant: ReDim a(9)
Dim b As Variant: ReDim b(2)
a(0) = b
```

Comment: Bear in mind that smaller code does not necessarily mean better (faster, clearer, more recommendable, etc.) one. You are instantiating two arrays (for what two lines of code sounds reasonable); then you are storing one of these arrays in a given position of the other one (another additional code line). To accomplish what you want, any programming language would have to perform the same 3 actions; in some cases the syntax might be slightly shorter, but less than 3 lines?! BTW, if you want to reduce the code size, you should replace Dim a As Variant: ReDim a(9) with Dim a(9) As Variant.

Comment: Thanks, concern is not code size but speed/memory. This is just a simple example. In reality I have large multi-dimensional nested array structures and need to do a lot of dynamic redim of inner arrays on the fly, so it's a real overhead. The second example creates two 3-element arrays, first `b` then `a(0)`, then copies the (empty) contents of `b` to `a(0)`. In C I would just make `a(0)` be a pointer to `b`. Not a criticism of VBA since it has its uses, just wondering if I'm missing a way to do it without the overhead.

Comment: Try `a(0) = Split(Space(2))` :) Note, that your code `ReDim b(2)` makes a 3-element array, since `Option Base` not declared.

Comment: If your concern is memory, you should think very carefully your whole algorithm because using too many arrays with more than 1D consumes lots of memory; and, in most of cases, these situations can be avoided with a different approach to the problem. In any case, if you want to rely on this approach your code might not be optimised further (other than the length of its syntax). As said, these 3 actions (creating the two arrays with the corresponding sizes and storing the second one in the given location) represent the absolute minimum to accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to `Dim` and `ReDim` your array. If you want your array to have a static size, just use `Dim`:

```
Dim a(9)
```

To make the first element an empty, two-element sub-array, you can use the `Array()` function and assign the elements an initial value of `Empty`:

```
a(0) = Array(Empty, Empty)
```

Tests:

```
Debug.Print IsEmpty(a(0))        ' False (holds sub-array)
Debug.Print IsEmpty(a(4))        ' True (uninitialized main element)
Debug.Print IsEmpty(a(0)(0))     ' True (uninitialized subarray element)
```